# NSMenu canelTracking is not working on Mac OSx 10.5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-leopard, nsmenu, nscombobox

I m using NSComboBox inside NSMenu to show a list of items. When I choose any option in NSComboBox menu should get dismissed.

To dismiss NSMenu I m using cancelTrackingWithoutAnimation for 10.6 and above and it works fine. In case of 10.5 i am using cancelTracking but it is not dismissing NSMenu.

Comment: There are a couple sample code that uses `cancelTracking`, try run those in 10.5 and see if they work or not. If they don't work then it's a bug, if they do work then your code is probably the reason why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using carbon API `CancelMenuTracking()`,

```
CancelMenuTracking(
  MenuRef   inRootMenu,
  Boolean   inImmediate,
  UInt32    inDismissalReason)
```

Used _NSGetCarbonMenu to get the menuref of NSMenu.

menuRef = _NSGetCarbonMenu(myMenu);

`CancelMenuTracking(menuRef,YES,kHIMenuDismissedByCancelMenuTracking);` for 10.5 and `CancelMenuTracking(menuRef,YES,0);` for 10.6 and above